# How to smooth swipe through vertical ion-slides?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a component which makes use of the ionic component ion-slides but when I test this on mobile the slides are scrolling 1 per 1. This looks really snappy when you do a harder scroll.

What you expect that the slides do is smoothly scroll through your slides when you do a harder scroll than just one.

In web the scroll is working like it should, but on mobile it feels really snappy.

Here is a reproduced stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-aecpl2

And this is the original home.html:

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
   <ion-grid no-padding fixed class="s-margin-l">
        <mm-restaurant-slide-card [restaurantList]="restaurantsList" class="mb-2"></mm-restaurant-slide-card>
   </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

I hope someone could tell me if this is a familiar problem on android mobile phone?

Comment: Do you found something? I'm looking for the same right now...

Comment: Yes look in the documentation of this library: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/. If you didnt find anything remind me by tomorrow

Comment: I tried with freeMode: true but that changed nothing.